# Is it possible to remove all default telegram bot commands

Tags: telegram-bot

I need to completely remove the  /start and all the slash commands from the telegram bot that we are building. Is it possible to do such thing? I cannot find any mention of this anywhere.

Comment: I think, that no. How you can talk with bot without /start command  ?

Comment: by default there only is /start and you don't need to do anything when you receive that command.

Comment: Guys, thanks for responding. I'm trying to make the bot as user friendly as possible without making the user type the slashes commands. But I guess that is the way it is with Telegram Bot.

Comment: I see, well you can also just parse all messages by disabling [Privacy Mode](https://core.telegram.org/bots#privacy-mode) and then run functions or whatever based on any input. However, /start will still always happen if a single user clicks start on a bot (this does not happen with groups)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is one of Telegram bot bugs

you can not remove all of commands
but you can :

**remove the bot , recreate it**